# Why the verb "wage" is always used in a context of war?

Tags: verbs

Why people don't use: "To carry out" instead? And I've never seen such a verb being not used in a context of war.

Comment: Phrases like this fall into a category sometimes called [verb-noun collocation](http://www.macmillandictionaries.com/MED-Magazine/June2004/20-Language-Study-Collocation-US.htm); in other words, an idiomatic usage of a verb with a restricted set of  objects.

Comment: because of alliteration

Comment: You have to be *stark dressed* to *wage peace*.

Comment: you can wage a campaign to end xyz  (but a campaign is a synonym to war)

Comment: Doubly interesting because while *To carry out* never applies to war there is the very different context in which one might *carry war to* or war might be *carried to* a territory…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It usage with reference to war dates back to the 15th century and it has become idiomatic:

> - ***[When you wage something](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/wage), you carry it out***: for example, a warmonger is someone whose primary goal is to wage wars. The word is of Germanic origin, and it's related to both gage and wed, with their underlying meanings of "to pledge."

(Vocabulary.com)

***[wage](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wage) (v.):***

> - ***c. 1300, "give (something) as surety, deposit as a pledge," from Old North French wagier "to pledge"***  (Old French gagier, "to pledge, guarantee, promise; bet, wager, pay," Modern French gager), from wage (see wage (n.)).
> - ***Meaning "to carry on, engage in" (of war, etc.) is attested from mid-15c.***, probably from earlier sense of "to offer as a gage of battle, agree to engage in combat" (mid-14c.).

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=carry%20out%20war%2C%20wage%20war&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccarry%20out%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwage%20war%3B%2Cc0) wage war vs carry out war.

Comment: According to the OED both *wage* and *gage* are of Anglo-Norman, Old French origin. It is the popular Latin *wadium* which seems to be of German origin. *Etymology:  < Anglo-Norman, Old French (north-eastern) wage (Anglo-Latin wagium ) = Central Old French guage , gage  (modern French gage ), Provençal gage-s , Italian gaggio  < popular Latin *wadium , of Germanic origin: see wed n*